# Delete daily filebeat index

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat, elk

I'm using the kibana interface to manage ELK in Kubernetes. ELK creates a new filebeat index every day `filebeat-<date>` with several GB.

I created a index lifecycle policy but I can only add it to an existing index.
I want it to be added to new filebeat indexes as well.

Kibana has the concept of index patters but I cannot find the place to link it to a policy.

I want to know if this is possbile to do in Kibana?

I'm using kibana 7.12.0

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the ILM policy to the index as per https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.12/ilm-with-existing-indices.html

however it should be handled automatically in 7.12, unless you've changed the default config? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/7.12/ilm.html

Comment: Hi thanks. There's no filebeat template index. If I create one will it attach to the new indexes. I never used ELK or Kibana so I'm not sure if it will work.